# How to avoid mutating logging records

Tags: python, python-logging

I have an application running with two logging handlers, one to the console in which I wish to shorten exception messages, and one to a file where I want the full traceback.

However, whichever handler is called first (in my case, console) overrides the exception message inside the `LogRecord` object passed around, and since this is both mutable and not cloned, this affects the output of any handlers called later.

Minimal example (IDLE 3.10.5):

```py
>>> def div0():
...     try:
...         1/0
...     except Exception:
...         logging.exception("Oops")

# At this point, calling div0() prints the message and traceback using the default logging handler

>>> class ShortExceptionFormatter(logging.Formatter):
...     def formatException(self, ei):
...         return repr(ei[1])

>>> consoleHandler = logging.StreamHandler()
>>> consoleHandler.setFormatter(ShortExceptionFormatter())
>>> rootLogger = logging.getLogger()
>>> rootLogger.addHandler(consoleHandler)

# Now both handlers print the message and traceback, which is undesirable

>>> div0()
    ERROR:root:Oops
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#2>", line 3, in div0
    ZeroDivisionError: division by zero
    Oops
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<pyshell#2>", line 3, in div0
    ZeroDivisionError: division by zero

# By removing the default logging handler, my custom formatter works as expected

>>> defaultHandler = rootLogger.handlers.pop(0)
>>> div0()
    Oops
    ZeroDivisionError('division by zero')

# But now if we add the default handler back, it's overridden by the custom formatter

>>> rootLogger.addHandler(defaultHandler)
>>> div0()
    Oops
    ZeroDivisionError('division by zero')
    ERROR:root:Oops
    ZeroDivisionError('division by zero')
```

**Is there a clean and proper way to isolate the record objects between each handler, and/or to avoid mutating the records?** This problem stems from `record.exc_text` being mutated, but my question applies to any arguments that may be modified by a handler, filter or other function.

My current workaround is to backup and restore the `exc_text` argument of the record, but this is obviously not an ideal solution:

```py
class ShortExceptionFormatter(logging.Formatter):
    def format(self, record):
        exc_text = record.exc_text
        record.exc_text = ''
        message = super().format(record)
        record.exc_text = exc_text
        return message
```

Comment: The docs don't give a *much* better solution, but they do suggest that you can set `exc_text` to None rather than explicitly restoring its previous value: *"...you should be careful if you have more than one Formatter subclass which customizes the formatting of exception information. In this case, you will have to clear the cached value (by setting the exc_text attribute to None) after a formatter has done its formatting..."* (https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.format)

Comment: @slothrop nice catch, I had looked for this in formatException's doc but not format. I'll add that `exc_text` should also be set to None _before_ calling the formatter, in the case where one wants to delegate the main formatting job to `logging.Formatter.format`.