# Logging: How to use different formatters for different handlers?

Tags: python

I'm trying to set up two logging handlers, one of which has a custom Formatter for exceptions. Here's what I've tried:

```
import logging

def log_something():
    log.error("Normal error")
    try:
        raise RuntimeError("Exception!")
    except Exception as e:
        log.exception(e)

class MyFormatter(logging.Formatter):

    def formatException(self, exc_info):
        return "Too bad"

s_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
s_handler.setFormatter(MyFormatter(fmt="My formatter: %(message)s"))
f_handler = logging.FileHandler("log.txt")

log = logging.getLogger()
log.addHandler(f_handler) # first
log.addHandler(s_handler) # second -- why does the order matter?

log_something()
```

The output is:

```
My formatter: Normal error
My formatter: Exception!
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "exception.py", line 6, in log_something
    raise RuntimeError("Exception!")
RuntimeError: Exception!
```

So it seems that the formatException method of my custom formatter doesn't get called. However, when I reverse the two addHandler calls like so:

```
log.addHandler(handler)
log.addHandler(f_handler)
```

the output is as expected:

```
My formatter: Normal error
My formatter: Exception!
Too bad
```

Also in either case the logging outputs to the file and the stream are exactly the same. My questions:

1. How come that the formatter of the handler that is added first is used for the subsequent handler as well? I thought that the formatter "belongs" to the handler, and that when I add different handlers to different formatters the wouldn't interfere.
2. Why does the format() method get called in either case, but the formatException() method only if the handler with the custom formatter is added first?

It seems that the formatter of the second handler is ignored and that always the formatter of the first handler is used. Why is that? I thought the formatter "belonged" to the handler, and that different handlers could use different formatters?

Comment: Similar: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76007043/how-to-avoid-mutating-logging-records

Comment: Per the Python docs: *"you should be careful if you have more than one Formatter subclass which customizes the formatting of exception information. In this case, you will have to clear the cached value (by setting the exc_text attribute to None) after a formatter has done its formatting"* - https://docs.python.org/3/library/logging.html#logging.Formatter.format

Comment: Thanks! I pored both over the documentation and the logging module's source code and somehow completely missed this. Whew!

Answer (score 0):

With the comment from [slothrop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/765091/slothrop), I immediately solved the problem. Here's the result (log an exception one-liner on stderr and the full stack trace in the logfile):

```
import logging
from pprint import pprint
import pdb

def log_something():
    log.error("Normal error: %d", 5)
    try:
        raise RuntimeError("Exception!")
    except Exception as e:
        log.exception(e)

class FmtExcOneliner(logging.Formatter):

    def format(self, rec):
        # ---- copied from logging.__init__
        rec.message = rec.getMessage()
        if self.usesTime():
            rec.asctime = self.formatTime(rec, self.datefmt)
        s = self.formatMessage(rec)
        # ----
        if rec.exc_info:
           return ("{s} (@{x.co_filename}:{x.co_firstlineno})"
                   .format(s=s, x=rec.exc_info[2].tb_frame.f_code))
        else:
            return s

s_handler = logging.StreamHandler()
s_handler.setFormatter(FmtExcOneliner(
    fmt="Stream: %(levelname)s %(asctime)s %(message)s"))
f_handler = logging.FileHandler("log.txt", "w")
f_handler.setFormatter(logging.Formatter(fmt="File: %(message)s"))

log = logging.getLogger()
log.addHandler(f_handler)
log.addHandler(s_handler)


log_something()
```